# How to interrupt the Bluetooth file transfer in Xamarin forms?

Tags: android, xamarin

Currently, I'm using `bluetoothsocket.close` in code to stop file transfer. But using this disconnects the Bluetooth device. How to interrupt file transfer Without using socket close.

Comment: just stop writing data into socket.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Pretty sure that you have to close the stream and not the socket itself.

Try:

```
bluetoothSocket.OutputStream.Close();
```

or

```
bluetoothSocket.InputStream.Close();
```

Reference here: [BluetoothSocket Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.bluetooth.bluetoothsocket?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)
Hope this helps.

Comment: You should be able to simply re-connect when you Need to read again after Closing it. You should be able to do that with `bluetoothSocket.InputStream.Connect();`